# Eliminate whitespaces in table columns

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I have to convert `varchar` column into `number` column. While doing that I'm getting error `invalid number`. After debugging the values some has whitespaces and some other values entered as `56.678.90`. Below is the query I tried to convert `varchar` into `number`,

`select cast('45.56.78' as number) from dual` or

`select cast ('  ' as number) from dual`

Both the values which I have entered in the above query will be there under column `'lddfc'` in table `entry_header`. Column `lddfc` has records as `456.99`, `456.89.43`, and whitespace. How can I display these values as `number`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what variant of SQL you are using but if it's T-SQL you could remove leading and trailing spaces using `LTRIM(RTRIM(yourValue))`. Not sure about syntax for PL/SQL.

So your code would be `select cast(LTRIM(RTRIM('45.56.78')) AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL`

I don't think that you can convert `'45.56.78'` to a number though without removing one of the decimal points.